# XMLUnit Compare Xml comparing wrong Nodes

Tags: xml, compare, xmlunit

I am having an issue when you have the parent node in different order. 
For example:

Sample XML1

```
<level1>
   <name>FirstParent</name>
   <level2>
        <somefield>AAA</somefield>
   </level2>
   <level2>
        <somefield>BBB</somefield>
   </level2>       
</level1>
<level1>
   <name>SecondParent</name>
   <level2>
        <somefield>CCC</somefield>
   </level2>
   <level2>
        <somefield>DDD</somefield>
   </level2>
</level1>
```

Sample XML2

```
<level1>
   <name>SecondParent</name>
   <level2>
        <somefield>DDD</somefield>
   </level2>
   <level2>
        <somefield>CCC</somefield>
   </level2>
</level1>
<level1>
   <name>FirstParent</name>
   <level2>
        <somefield>BBB</somefield>
   </level2>
   <level2>
        <somefield>AAA</somefield>
   </level2>          
</level1>
```

When I debug the RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier, I see that it is getting FirstParent as controlnode and SecondParent as testnode. And, therefore, concluding correctly that the nodes are different. But what I need is to compare both FirstParent and both SeconParent with their correct match in the other file.

So, seems that I need to sort the higher level nodes first (?).

Does anybody know how can I overcome this? What should I check/modify/implement differently to pass the right tandem of parents to the ElementQualifier ?

Maybe, with the right directions, I can develop what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified whether you're using XMLUnit 1 or 2, but in version 2 (2.0.0-alpha-04) and using the DiffBuilder I was having this problem. The solution is to construct the Diff passing a non-default ElementSelector to Default Matcher:

```
import org.xmlunit.diff.Diff;
import org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder;
import org.xmlunit.diff.ElementSelectors;
import org.xmlunit.diff.DefaultNodeMatcher;
```

.
.
.

```
Diff diff = DiffBuilder.
            compare(myExpectedResultXmlObj).
            withTest(myCompareToXmlObj).
            withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName)). 
            build();

Assert.assertFalse(diff.toString(), diff.hasDifferences());
```

The key part being the withNodeMatcher line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about the conditions that are necessary to pick up the same branches of your document.  From your description you want to compare the the two `level1` elements with their order swapped.  It sounds as if you wanted to identify the matching pairs by looking into the text content of the first `name` child element nested into it.  And just on this text, nothing else.

This is not what `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` does.  It compares the element names and nested texts of *all* child elements.  And since the order of `somefield` elements is swapped, the nodes you'd like to compare are not eligible.

You see XMLUnit picking the `level1` elements in order as it falls back to doing just that when no matching pairs of nodes have been found at all.  If you set `compareUnmatched` to `false` you'd get `CHILD_NODE_NOT_FOUND` differences instead.

In XMLUnit 1.x (2.x hasn't been released, yet) you'll have to write an `ElementQualifier` that embeds the logic you need yourself, there is no built-in `ElementQualifier` that did exactly what you want.

Comment: Hey Stefan, thanks for the reply. Are you sure that is the ElementQualifier class the one I need to develop? Im not much of a Java guy but I can give it a try. Could you point me out what or when or where the selection of nodes for comparison begins?  That way I can put the code to sort the elements before that and just send the right couple of nodes to compare to the existing functions. TY

Comment: That may end up being a lot more complex.  See the `compareNodeList` method in `DifferenceEngine`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide your own `ElementQualifier` implementation. `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` will potentially match the same element from one document against multiple elements from the other.

Comment: Inside the RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier I have the compareNodes call. That call is being passed FirstParent as currentControl and SecondParent as currentTest. Do you know when/where is that call being made?

Comment: `compareNodes()` is called by the interface method `qualifyForComparison()`, which is called by the `compare()` method of `Diff`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I also needed to add the method `checkForSimilar()` on the `DiffBuilder`.

Without it, the assert was in error saying that the sequence of the nodes was not the same (the position in the child list was not the same)

My code was :

```
Diff diff = DiffBuilder
    .compare(myExpectedResultXmlObj)
    .withTest(myCompareToXmlObj)
    .checkForSimilar()
    .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))
    .build();
```